# How to use stored procedure on MVC 5 with DbContext?

Tags: stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext

In SQL 2008 Query I just execute and it returns 1 if successful. Now how do I do this in MVC 5 EF dbcontext?

```
usp_CreateNewAccount usernamehere, passwordhere, emailhere
```

I created my Controller item using the Entity Framework, and edit the controller Create method.

```
 db.Users.Add(user);
 db.Users.SqlQuery("usp_CreateNewAccount fsdfsdf, sdfsdfsd, dasda");
 db.SaveChanges();
```

it gives no result. I can't create user. Any possible solution?

Comment: My experience with entity framework is that procedures does not always work when comes to automatic generated code. In your code I don't see any parameters when calling stored procedure. Calling SQlQuery from Users is also not the best idea, I would rather use db.Database.SqlQuery. Also matters what your procedure contains. You should include it here because it can represent the main problem.

Comment: Next thing is why adding user to Users collection and right after put calling a stored procedure. In that time user cannot exist in the database yet, so procedure cannot work with that record.

Comment: @JadaVonRuth I'm having hard time using dbcontext, cause I new in MVC 5 the VS 2015 did not showing any errors, only blank pages

Comment: Coud you post your procedure, what it should do? Does it enhance the record your are trying to insert using "db.Users.Add(user);" or does it only insert row to Users table?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have stored procedure `usp_CreateNewAccount`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CreateNewAccount
@usernamehere NVARCHAR(...), 
@passwordhere NVARCHAR(...), 
@emailhere NVARCHAR(...)
AS
BEGIN
-- insert query here
END
```

Then you can use `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery` with parameters like this one:

```
using (var db = new DataContext()) // DataContext is your DBContext name
{
    var userName = new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "usernamehere",
        DbType = DbType.String,
        Value = "fsdfsdf"
    };

    var password = new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "passwordhere",
        DbType = DbType.String,
        Value = "sdfsdfsd"
    };

    var email = new SqlParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "emailhere",
        DbType = DbType.String,
        Value = "dasda"
    };

    // suppose "User" table exists with "db.Users" as DbSet<User> collection
    db.Database.SqlQuery<User>("EXEC usp_CreateNewAccount {0}, {1}, {2}", new Object[] { userName, password, email });
}
```

There's no reason to use `db.Users.Add` and `db.SaveChanges` method here since insert and save operation already handled by stored procedure query.